# Warning message: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

Tags: c

Written a function with `unsigned char` arguments as shown below

```
void Address_set(unsigned char x1,unsigned char y1,unsigned char x2,unsigned char y2)
```

The above function is called in `main()` function of C Code as

```
Address_set(0,0,239,319);
```

I received a warning as

large integer implicitly truncated to `unsigned type [-Woverflow]`

How to avoid this warning.

Comment: By not using larger values than the types can handle.

Comment: Either change (unsigned char y2) to int, or avoid using a number that's greater than max value of unsigned char

Comment: What did you expect, trying to convert 319 to [an `unsigned char`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm)?

Comment: Since we are dealing with `unsigned char`s, the value would be "wrapped".

Comment: Then what will be the possible method to pass 319 to that function?

Answer (score 2):

The range of `unsigned char` is [0 ... 255], the value 319 is truncated (wrap-around) to `319 % 256 = 63`

> How to avoid this warning.

The value is still truncated even if you can avoid this warning using a cast:

```
Address_set(0,0,239,(unsigned char)319);
```

Use a longer type, i.e: `unsigned short`

Comment: Or pass a smaller value (e.g. 255 instead of 319).

Comment: After changing it to unsigned short. It looks fine. void Address_set(unsigned short x1,unsigned short y1,unsigned short x2,unsigned short y2)